# how to read a text using condition if

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have an issue and I need your help. here is the problem. I have inside a folder some excel files that I have to open automatically in order to make some operations. Those files have the same name except the number of the files like this:

Folder name : Extraction_Files
Files name :     - "System_Extraction_Supplier_1"
                 - "System_Extraction_Supplier_2"
                 - "System_Extraction_Supplier_3"

The number of files can change so i used a loop Do While to count the number of files, then the plan is to use a loop for I =1 to ( number of files) to open all of theme.

please read my code. I know that i used a wrong way to read file name using a loop for but I share it because I don't have an other idea.

Here is my code :

```
Sub OpenFiles ()

    Dim MainPath as String 
    Dim CommonPath as String 
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

   ' the main path is " C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\System_Extraction_Supplier_i"
   'with i = 1 to Count ( file number )


    CommonPath = "C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\System_Extraction_Supplier_*"

   'counting automatically the file number

    Filename = Dir ( CommonPath )

    Do While Filename <> "" 

       Count = Count + 1 
       Filename = Dir ()

    Loop

'the issue is below because this code generate a MsgBox showing a MainPath with the index i like this
'"C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\System_Extraction_Supplier_i" 
' so vba can not find the files

    For i = 1 To count 

      MainPath = "C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\System_Extraction_Supplier_" & "i" 
      MsgBox  MainPath  & 
      Workbooks.Open MainPath 

    Next 

End Sub
```

what is the best approach to this?

Comment: Why not do what your doing in the `For` loop in the `While` loop?  Currently `"i"` is a string, for the value of `i` just use `i` (i.e. without quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not count as you open them. You're already identifying them so why not open each file as you go:

```
Sub OpenFiles()

    Dim Filename As String
    Dim CommonPath As String
    Dim Count As Integer

    CommonPath = "C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\"

    Filename = Dir(CommonPath & "System_Extraction_Supplier_*")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        MsgBox Filename
        Workbooks.Open CommonPath & Filename
        Count = Count + 1
        Filename = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

PS. It might be worth adding `.xl*` or similar to the end of your search pattern to prevent Excel trying to open files that aren't Excel files:

```
Filename = Dir(CommonPath & "System_Extraction_Supplier_*.xl*")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Apparently the machine doesn't handle a parameter " * " as a remaining part with .open function as it do it to count them. so it generate a path with character * as a character and I got an error message saying that a file doesn't exist :(

Comment: How odd. It works perfectly on my machine here. * is the correct wildcard to use with `Dir`. Does the MsgBox pop up with a filename before the error? If not, then the pattern you're using `System_Extraction_Supplier_` doesn't actually match any filenames in that folder.

Comment: Hi @CLR it works. I just removed a Var which has been seted as string containing the  File name with " * " at the end. So I've done it again like you directly with a path and it works perfectly. thanks again CLR. All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open all folders, in a specific folder, which start with "NewFile_", one loop only is needed:

```
Sub OpenFolders()

    Dim path As String: path = ""C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\""
    Dim fileStart As String: fileStart = "System_Extraction_Supplier_"
    Dim Fso As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object

    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(path)

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, fileStart) Then
            Shell "explorer.exe " & objSubFolder, vbNormalFocus
            Debug.Print objSubFolder.Name
        End If
    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Folders in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) are opened with the `Shell "explorer.exe "` command. The code opens every folder in `"C:\yourFile\"`, which contains `NewFile_` in the name. This check is done with  `If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, fileStart) Then`.

Comment: Hi @Vityata thanks for your help.  I used your code but i got an error in this line :     Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(path)                the message error is : " Run time error '5' : Invalide procedure call or Argument "

Comment: @DataScientist - strange, it worked when I tried it, probably remove the last `\\` in the path string.

Comment: Hi @Vityata I removed " \ "  from path String. there is no more bug but no result neither. so I added "\" in the beginning of fileStart String and no result also . Sorry to bother u with this but I like your code and I want make it works

Comment: @DataScientist - in your case it should be like this: `"C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\"` Then `System_Extraction_Supplier_`, without the `*`.